# Meaning of singular Jacobian and workarounds to Newton's method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm currently working with Galerkin's method to solve differential equations and I have to retrieve unknown coefficients for the truncate expansion. This is just to set the background for why I need to solve a system of possible non-linear equations.

Several of my problems turn out to have a singular Jacobian which prevents me from using Newton's method. The following figure is a "spy" from my Jacobian:

[image: Spy of a Jacobian; blue dots are non zero elements; red circle indicates zero elements which could transform the Jacobian into a non-singular one.]

In the figure, a blue dot means a non-zero entry in the Jacobian and a red circle indicates a "missing" (zeroed) entry that could be helpful if I want to turn my Jacobian into a non-singular one. I'm outrageous cause the Jacobian *J* was built as a 64x64 matrix and just 3 elements "made" it singular. (this is a gag only, I know those missing elements have physical meaning :-D )

The Newton's method I am referring to is the multivariate version:

$$X^{(k+1)} = X^{(k)} - J^{-1} \cdot [f_1(X^{(k)}),\,f_2(X^{(k)}),\ldots f_N(X^{(k)})]^T$$

**So, my questions are:**

(1) What is the meaning for this sparse Jacobian to be singular?

(2) Between 64 variables -- i.e. 4,096 derivatives from which 652 are non-zeros --, 3 strategically placed derivatives are evaluated as zeros. This is enough to throw away all valid information?

(3) Is there any workaround to apply Newton's method with this Jacobian? For example, could I use parts of the Jacobian to update at least some of the coordinates?

Comment: Have you tried solving $(J^T J) \Delta x = J^T f(x)$? This would be a least-squares solution to the newton-step equations.

Comment: Hi, @AlexR! Thanks for the input :-D! Yes, I should try to solve for $\Delta x$. I've just tried your idea to understand which are the possibilities and I've find out that my $(J^T\,J)$ is singular as well (a symmetric, dense-matrix without zeroed entries, but it is still singular). I'm still lost...

Comment: That's a bad booty. Maybe you should elaborate on the exact function used if that's possible.

Comment: It is a system of equations (linear in this case) generated by 55 inner products (definite integrations with different basis functions) plus 9 functions related to boundary conditions. After, I do the Jacobian using the derivatives from the system equations. It is complicated to resume it here. I'll try to do something simpler that hopefully got the same problem and then we can go on. Thanks, @AlexR, anyway...

Comment: If the equations come from a finite element method, can you ensure that the solution is unique given the BC and basis functions?

Comment: There is probably a problem with your boundary conditions